# How to auto-submit form after entering text of certain length into input field

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I am looking for an auto-submit function for my form which should submit it once user enters text of certain length (lets say 15 chars) into an input field.

Is there any function in jQuery that would constantly (in very short intervals) check the length of the text in the input field and run a function once the required number of chars is met? Any ideas?

EDIT:
I am looking for this functionality:
User enters the page with the form - autofocuses on the input field - user reads a barcode with a scanner - then the barcode number is pasted in the input field (not keyup, keydown event) and the form is autosubmitted.

SOLVED:
Used this function to catch changes in input field:

```
$(#inputField).bind('input propertychange', function(){
  dostuff();  
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of checking for length of text in input field at particular `interval`, lets attach `keyup` event handler to the text field. Every time the `keyup` event is fired, we'll check if the length exceeds 15. If it does then we'll submit the form with `.submit()` API.

```
$('yourTextBoxSelector').on("change paste keyup", function(){
    if($(this).val().length >15){
        $('yourFormSelector').submit()
    }
});
```

UPDATE : jQuery has an event `paste`. You can use it...

Comment: This is certainly gonna work, thanks a lot, but I should have added this important note - what if I copy the desired text of length 15 and paste it to the input field. How does your answer transfer to that case?

Comment: @JanWrm I have updated my answer to take into account copying and pasting.

Comment: Thanks Sam, the "keyup" event is fine. What I am actually gonna do is that I will be using the scanning pistol (barcode reader) - its pluged in using usb and once it reads a barcode it pastes it to where a pointer is focused. In this case there will be no "keyup" event. Any ideas in this situation?

Comment: @JanWrm : Simple.. You can use jQuery's `paste` event in that case... Check the updated answer :)

Comment: SOLVED! I ran into a event called "input propertychange" which does exactly what I need. Thanks for help all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would approach this. This also takes into account the user copying and pasting into the input area.

Jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/PgzrU/4/

Code below:

```
var max = 15;
$('input').change(function(e)
{  
  if ($(this).val().length > max) { alert('form fired') }
}).keyup(function(e)
{  
  if ($(this).val().length > max) { alert('form fired') }
});​
```

Comment: Hi, you can attach multiple events like `$('yourSelector').on('change keyup', function(){})`