# Submit the form just after entering the word in search form

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have a search form and I want to submit the form just after user has entered any word in input field. I don't want any submit button or enter key. How can I do this ?

Comment: you are looking for the onchange event and the form.submit() method.

Comment: I don't think the `onchange` event fires until the user presses Enter or leaves the field.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447045/how-to-auto-submit-form-after-entering-text-of-certain-length-into-input-field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly .. why don't you submit the call when the user is idle for some time

Comment: try `.onkeydown()` or `.onkeypress()` events in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
$('#text-field-id').keyup(function()
{
    $('#form-id').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `javascript` for this like this

```
<script>
function submit()
{
    form.submit();
} </script>

<input type="text" onkeyup="submit();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="searchbox" onkeypress="document.getElementById('myform').submit()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="autocomplete">
function autocomplete()
{
    formid.submit();
} 

Also, You may try out some ajax.
```