# jQuery: Submit form on paste

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit, onpaste

A data entry person is putting email address into a form and it would be helpful if the form submitted each time he pasted in an address so it would be ready for the next paste.  Other code within the setTimeout also works fine--just not the form submission.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
$("#email").on("paste", function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#cancelemail").submit();
    }, 0);
});


<form action="done.php" method="post" id="cancelemail">

Address to be removed: <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove">

</form>
```

Comment: Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447045/how-to-auto-submit-form-after-entering-text-of-certain-length-into-input-field $('yourTextBoxSelector').on("change paste keyup", function(){ if($(this).val().length >15){ $('yourFormSelector').submit() } }); But Hey, you should try search for it [over the net](https://www.google.ca/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=jQuery:%20Submit%20form%20on%20paste).

Comment: @JPod jquery has a 'paste' event

Comment: Rather than using the `paste -> browser-submit -> reload page` logic, would you find it more friendly to use this logic? `paste -> AJAX submit -> clear input -> maintain focus on input -> display small success/error message below input box`

Comment: Is it possible that a set timeout of 0 is just too fast? What happens if you up the set timeout to just one second?

Comment: @jonnybot "just one second" its quite a lot, one second IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's strange, triggering the submit doesn't seem to be working for me unless I remove the submit button from the HTML, but triggering the submit button actually does ?

```
$("#email").on("paste", function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('[name=submit]').trigger('click')
    });
});
```

[Fiddle with button, triggering submit -> not working ?](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ay3E/)
[Fiddle without button, triggering submit -> works](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ay3E/1/)
[Fiddle with button, triggering button click -> works](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ay3E/2/)

Comment: @A.Wolff - Thanks for the link, now that I've read that, I realize that I already knew that, but just couldn't for the life of me figure out why it wouldn't submit, and now it seems so obvious. It's one of those mistakes that I never I do myself, and you don't see it very often, but naming an element "submit" will indeed overwrite the native submit function attached to the form.

Comment: @A.Wolff: Your comment was exactly the problem with my original code too.  Thanks for leading us there adeneo.